# How to store a value based on another attribute value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to display some attribute of an element in a select, and store the displayed attributes in a value and a different attribute of the same element in another value.

```
render() {
const refertiItems = this.state.referti.map((referti, i) => {
  return (
    <option key={referti.hash_referto}>
      {referti.tipo_esame}-{referti.data_esame}
    </option>
  )
});

 return(
  <Label for="type" text="Descrizione Referto" />
    <select
      name="descrizioneReferto"
      placeholder="Selezionare Referto"
      onKeyPress={this.onEnter}
      value={this.state.referti.descrizioneReferto}
      onChange={this.handleInputChange}
    >
      <option default value="vuoto"></option>
      {refertiItems}
    </select>
```

So in this code i can store {referti.tipo_esame} and {referti.data_esame} in descrizioneReferto. I also need to store {referti.hash_referto} inside codiceReferto. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the key of the option element in the onChange function like this:

```
handleInputChange = (event, child) => {
   this.setState({
         descrizioneReferto: event.target.value,
         codiceReferto: child.key
   });
}
```

To use the material-ui select, change your code to:

```
<Select
  value={this.state.referti.descrizioneReferto}
  name="descrizioneReferto"
  onKeyPress={this.onEnter}
  placeholder="Selezionare Referto"
  onChange={this.handleInputChange}>
      <MenuItem value="vuoto"/>
   {refertiItems}
</Select>
```

and

```
const refertiItems = this.state.referti.map((referti, i) => {
  return <Menu key={referti.hash_referto}>
    {referti.tipo_esame}-{referti.data_esame}
  </option>
});
```

Comment: I dont think you can access the key without the wrapper.

Comment: i'm using material-ui in my project, how should i use it in this case?

Comment: i Updated my answer

Comment: in that way refertiItems is not called anywhere

Comment: cannot ready property key of undefined...in the handleInputChange

Comment: Does this happen if you select vuoto?

Comment: it doesn't happen if i select vuoto, but it happens when i do anything else in that page

Comment: https://codepen.io/mikirug/pen/aboqVKg sorry if it's settled in a wrong way

Comment: You are not giving the child of the map the key. Wrap the whole map with ul and remove the ul from the map function. That should work for you

Comment: sorry i gave you the wrong code... https://codepen.io/mikirug/pen/aboqVKg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199146/discussion-between-domino987-and-mikirug88).